# I want to make sure I have completely uninstalled anaconda

Tags: anaconda, hidden-files, macos-monterey

I am a beginner python programmer. I'm working on Monterey macOS. I decided to uninstall anaconda b/c i had installed a few packages into by my base environment and heard that it was best to not do that and instead only install packages into venv. So far I have uninstalled anaconda using anaconda clean, I have deleted the conda init logic from .zshrc, and rm -rf /opt/anaconda3. Lastly I have been removing some dot files from  my home directory that were somehow missed by anaconda clean; .anaconda, .conda, and .continuum (using the sudo command in the case of .continuum file). There appears to only be one file left; .config. I am not sure that this is actually an anaconda file and just want to be sure before I rm -rf.

Am I correct that this is a file left over from anaconda and it is ok to delete it? Further I intend on reinstalling anaconda and this time using venv for all my projects. Generally will it matter if i have missed a file or two. I really have not done much so far and just a few practice problems within jupyter notebook using pandas, numpy, and matplotlib